# How to play selected Media Item from UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmediaitem

I am trying to play `Media Item` that selected from `UITableView` in iOS.

I am using `MediaQuery` and i loaded songs list from iPod Library in my `UITableView`.

But i don't know how to play that selected songs from `UITableView`.

I know really basic simple AudioPlayer with following code.

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"sample" 
                                                              ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath] autorelease];
    self.player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error: nil] 
                   autorelease];
```

That is used of `ContentOfURL` that already located in resource.There is no need to retrieve songs from iPod Library.

Here is my CellForRowAtIndexPath Method Codes

```
MPMediaItemCollection *songs = [self.arrayOfSongs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [songs.items[0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

Now i am trying to play that retrieved songs from iPod Library with MediaQuery and that selected from `UITableView`

So How can i retrieve the URL and play the song from iPod Library that selected from `UITableView`?
Thanks for your reading.

Comment: no one to answer my question?

Comment: please post your cell for row at indexpath method, you need to implement the didselect row at indexpath method

Comment: Yes i also want to know that codes should write in didselectedrow method.
How to play that selected songs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   MPMediaItemCollection *songs = [self.arrayOfSongs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   MPMediaItem *item = [songs representativeItem];
   self.player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] error: nil] 
                   autorelease];

}
```